# Recursion and linked list

Tags: ruby, list, recursion

I want to see the representation of the linked list. I created a class for creating a linked list:

```
class LinkedListNode
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
  def print_values(list_node)
    print "#{list_node.value} --> "
    if list_node.next_node.nil?
      print "nil"
      return
    else
      print_values(list_node.next_node)
    end
  end

  node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
  node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
  node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)
  print_values(node3)
end
```

I get:

```
practice.rb:24:in `<class:LinkedListNode>': undefined method `print_values' for LinkedListNode:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Is recursion a method calling itself? Is it possible to have a method call another method to replace recursion? Or is calling another method not allowed?

Comment: Why is code like `node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)` inside the definition of `class LinkedListNode`?

Comment: I was getting undefined method on print_values when I had them outside (node1,node2,node3). So I thought I should put it inside the class to be defined. But i'm still getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is recursion a method calling upon itself?

Yes, generally. For specifics, examples, and exceptions see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

You may be able to understand recursion in your own code if you simplify your method.

The code that you wrote is more akin to procedural code, whereas Ruby typically uses object oriented code that is more akin to this:

```
class LinkedListNode

  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end

  # This is how to write a typical Ruby recursive method.
  # Notice the method does something with this object's value,
  # then transfers control to the next object's same method name.

  def to_s
    "#{value} --> " + (next_node ? next_node.to_s : "nil")
  end

end

# This code is moved out of your class definition.
# This fixes one of the errors in your original code.

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)

print node3.to_s
```

> Is it possible to have a method call on another method to replace recursion?

Yes, generally. For example in your code, you could call a method that uses iteration instead of recursion, something like this example.

Recursion:

```
  def to_s
    "#{value} --> " + (next_node ? next_node.to_s : "nil")
  end
```

Iteration:

```
  def to_s
    s = ""
    node = self
    while node != nil
      s += "#{value} --> " 
      node = next_node
    end
    s += "nil"
  end
```

An algorithm that is implemented using iteration often runs much faster than a similar algorithm that is implemented using recursion.

Some kinds of recursion (including your code here) are much more efficient than other kinds of recursion. Your code is a good example of code that can use efficient [tail call optimization](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/214-tail-call-optimisation-in-ruby-mri).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on using recursion and not using it. Both examples helped a lot, along with TCO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print_values` method is an *instance* method, though it does not use the instance in it.

I believe you meant to use the instance data for your implementation:

```
class LinkedListNode
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
  def print_values
    print "#{value} --> "
    if next_node.nil?
      print "nil"
      return
    else
      next_node.print_values
    end
  end
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)
node3.print_values
```

Another option is to make the method a *static* method, which does not need an instance, which will look like:

```
class LinkedListNode
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
  def self.print_values(list_node)
    print "#{list_node.value} --> "
    if list_node.next_node.nil?
      print "nil"
      return
    else
      print_values(list_node.next_node)
    end
  end
end

  node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
  node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
  node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)
  LinkedListNode.print_values(node3)
```

Both options will be considered *recursive*, since the method calls itself. There are no rules about recursion (calling another method is allowed), but there are things you need to be aware of, like if you don't have a good *stopping condition*, your method might "explode" with a stack overflow exception.

Comment: awesome answer thank you. When you refer to static method, is it class method that mudadosbwa mentions below? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should move the code dealing with class out of the class definition:

```
class LinkedListNode

  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end

  def print_values(list_node)
    print "#{list_node.value} --> "
    if list_node.next_node.nil?
        print "nil"
        return
    else
        print_values(list_node.next_node)
    end
  end
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)

node3.print_values(node3)
```

The code has an amount of other glitches, like `print_values` is ment to be a class method, rather than instance method, but the main problem is above. This is how I would turn the code to use class method for printing values:

```
class LinkedListNode

  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end 

  def self.print_values list_node
    print "#{list_node.value} --> "
    if list_node.next_node.nil?
        print "nil"
        return
    else
        print_values(list_node.next_node)
    end 
  end 
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)

LinkedListNode.print_values node3
```

Hope it helps.

**NB** The answer provided by @joelparkerhenderson is in fact a way better.

Comment: Thanks for the fix-up! I thought I tried with class out of the class definition. Should've taken a break. What difference does it make by making it a class method or non-class method?

Comment: Instance method is being called on instance, while class method is being called on a class. As a virtual example `5.plus(3)` would be an instance method, knowing about it’s called on an instance of integer, while `Integer.sum(5,3)` would be a class method.